# Handling stack count, Retrieve and Insert

Tags: c, pointers

```
Stack *S;
S = (Stack *)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
S->elements = malloc(sizeof(*S->elements)*tld->tldCount);

typedef struct Stack
{
    int capacity;
    int size;
    TLDNode** elements;
}Stack;

S->elements[S->size] = element;

or

S->elements[S->size] + 1 = element;
```

same for retrieving , do I take the current size or size -1

Comment: From what you've shown here, it seems like you're returning it correctly. What leads you to believe that it might be incorrect?

Comment: @PCLuddite I think there's some issue with return S->elements[S->size-1] ; Which led to it returning nothing.

Comment: When you say "return nothing", do you mean returning `NULL` or returning a garbage value (i.e. from deallocated memory)?

Comment: @PCLuddite I updated the question , NULL, it's returning like the struct without any content in it. I played around with the counts +1 -1 and it was returning but of course it's not returning correctly.

Comment: when calling malloc(), or calloc() or realloc(), 1) in C, do not cast the returned value because it is a `void *` so can be assigned to any other pointer.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: if you real code is referencing `stack` before the typedef is see by the complier, then the compiler will have raised a problem message.   Suggest placing the struct declarations after the typedef definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the S->size field is not set in the posted code, so how are we to guess? Suggest: S->size = tld->tldCount;

If my comment about setting the S->size field is followed, then neither suggested statement is correct as S->element[S->size] is accessing beyond the end of the element array. remember, in C, an array index starts with 0 and ends at 'array length -1'

If the `size` field is to indicate the number of entries in use in the `element` array, then this is how to handle setting another element:

```
S->elements[S->size] = element;
S->size++;
```

However, before doing any of that, this is needed:

```
S->size = 0;
```

when retrieving an element, say the most recently added element use:

```
S->size--;
element = S->elements[S-size];
```